# Cron with Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cron, umbraco

How can I schedule a task with Umbraco Cms. I would like to create scheduled emails with Umbraco 9.

I have tried unsuccessfully to get a documentation that could help. Could you please help or refer me to a documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just write an API-Controller, which does the work. Then use the windows task scheduler or a cron job on linux to call the url of the API.

```
public class EmailsController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Create()
    {
        // Do whatever you need
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Then call the url https://yoursite.com/umbraco/api/emails/create

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have a read about hosted services, which are a feature provided by the .NET 5 framework, and which Umbraco are using themselves.

In Umbraco v9, you can implement your own version by inheriting from `RecurringHostedServiceBase`

The documentation is lacking on this, but have a look at the Umbraco implementation to see some examples - https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/tree/v9/dev/src/Umbraco.Infrastructure/HostedServices

This is also a useful post that provides some further details - https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-9/106304-creating-scheduled-tasks-in-umbraco-9

An example:

```
public class YourScheduledTask : RecurringHostedServiceBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<YourScheduledTask> _logger;

    public YourScheduledTask(ILogger<YourScheduledTask> logger)
        : base(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task PerformExecuteAsync(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            // your logic here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("exception when persisting collections: {exception}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to resgister this in the IOC:

```
public class IoCComposer : IComposer
{
    public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHostedService<YourScheduledTask>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use cultiv's implementation of Hangfire in Umbraco (then you get a dashboard too), then setup the jobs in a composer.